# Composition of circle inversions

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, continued-fractions, complex-dynamics

I would like to understand the map of $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$
that results by iterating inversion in a unit circle.
Let $f(z)$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ invert $z$ in a unit circle
centered on $q_1$, and then in a unit circle centered on $q_2$,
etc.  Here is an example:

           
[image: Inversion]

The black path shows the trajectory of one point $z$, which
ends up inside the $q_5$ disk.
The blue vectors show the complete map's effect on a number of
(random) points.
The end result resembles an inversion in the $q_5$ circle,
but I imagine the plane is partitioned into regions that
behave similarly due to their relationship to the several circles of
inversion.
Is this a correct way to view this map?
And if so, is there a natural diagram to elucidate the partition?

I wonder if instead it may be better to view this map
as an approximation to another map?
For there is a continued-fraction representation of $f(z)$, as follows.
The inversion of $z$ in a unit circle centered
on $q$ can be expressed as $q + \frac{1}{z^* -q^*}$,
where ${\cdot}^*$ represents
the complex conjugate operation.
Then iterating this (say, five times) leads to this expression:
$$f(z) = 
q_5 +
        \frac{1}
                {q_4^*-q_5^* +
        \frac{1}
                {q_3-q_4+
        \frac{1}
                {q_2^*-q_3^*+
                \frac{1}
                        {q_1-q_2+\frac{1}{z^*-q_1^*}
                        }
        }
        }
        }
$$

I realize I have not posed a sharp question.  I am just seeking
some approach that helps understand the composition of circle
inversions, a bit far from my expertise.  Thanks for pointers or ideas!

Comment: As far as I can see, the composition of $n$ inversions is a Möbius transformation, or a Möbius transformation followed by conjugation, depending on the parity of $n$. It thus should not involve any partitions.

Comment: @Emil: Interesting!  And yet different $z$s follow rather disparate paths depending on whether they land in or out of specific disks.  Which is not to say I doubt you--rather, I appreciate this insight all the more!

Comment: This is just a bit of free association, but your question reminds me a bit of the notion of a Schottky group http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_group . I learned about them from the fantastic book "Indra's Pearls" by Mumford, Series, and Wright.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maps that you get by composing multiple inversions are exactly the [Möbius transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%25C3%25B6bius_transformation) and their reflections.

In terms of complex number coordinates for the planes, the compositions of even numbers of inversions are the fractional linear transformations
$$z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
(where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are complex numbers with $ad-bc\ne 0$, and multiplying all four of them by the same scalar leaves the transformation unchanged).
The compositions of odd numbers of inversions are their complex conjugates.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are looking for, however this wikipedia page seems a propos.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction

Comment: Thanks, Igor, yes, I looked at that wealth of information earlier without gaining significant insight.  Which is not to say it might not help!